# functions that are great for timing code to run after a delay -- is "timing" an adjective or gerund?

Tags: comprehension, present-participles, participle-clauses

Source: [*JavaScript for Kids: A Playful Introduction to Programming*](https://www.nostarch.com/javascriptforkids) by Nick Morgan

Example:

> In this chapter, you learned how to write JavaScript that runs only when you want it to. The *setTimeout* and *setInterval* functions are great for **timing code** to run after a delay or at certain intervals. If you want to run code when the user does something in the browser, you can use events like *click* and *mousemove*, but there are many others.

I'm a little bit confused with whether the word *timing* is used as an adjective that describes *code* or a gerund with *code* being the object of the verb *timing*. I'm leaning more toward the gerund option, however, because that simply makes much more sense here semantically. I'm not sure though. What do you think?

Comment: A noun functioning as an attribute.

Comment: The sentence could be paraphrased "are useful for those situations when you want to schedule code so that it will run after a delay or at certain intervals".  The *code* referenced in the sentence is not the code that creates the schedule, but the code that is executed on the specified schedule.

Comment: It's a "gerund-participle" derived from the verb "**to time**". You can use the *setTimeout* function **to time** a section of code so that it runs after a delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects of prepositions want nouns or noun phrases, so *for timing* means *timing* has to be a noun.

*-ing* forms of words that act as nouns are a form of verbal called gerunds.

While gerunds work as nouns, since they are a verbal, they can take objects.  So *code* is the object of the verbal *timing*.